# Delphi DataSnap. Passing parameters of type Variant into TDBXCommand to call stored proc

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, delphi-xe, datasnap

I'm trying to develop a simple app based on examples:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Creating_the_Server_Side_with_DataSnap_Server_(InterBase_Tutorial)

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Creating_a_Rich-Client_Interface_(InterBase_Tutorial)

I'm trying to implement a generic procedure to call DB stored procedures. The parameters in this procedure will be passed as a Variant array

**So the question is**:

How to pass Variant parameter to the procedure of the DataSnap server module?

Here so, for example, doesn't work, because TObject it not Variant; something like "SetVariant" i didn't find:

```
 function TdmServerModuleClient.callStoredProcedure(aSPName: String;
      aParamNames, aParamValues: Variant): Integer;
    begin
      if FcallStoredProcedureCommand = nil then
      begin
        FcallStoredProcedureCommand := FDBXConnection.CreateCommand;
        FcallStoredProcedureCommand.CommandType := TDBXCommandTypes.DSServerMethod;
        FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Text := 'TdmServerModule.callStoredProcedure';
        FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Prepare;
      end;
      FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetString(aSPName);
      FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Parameters[1].Value.SetObjectValue(aParamNames);
      FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Parameters[2].Value.SetObjectValue(aParamValues);
      FcallStoredProcedureCommand.ExecuteUpdate;
      Result := FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Parameters[1].Value.GetInt32;
    end;
```

I'm trying to do the following: convert multiple values into   array of Variant. I use this code to do this:

```
    function ValuesToArray(aValues: array of Variant): Variant;
    var
      i: Integer;
    begin
      Result := VarArrayCreate([Low(aValues), High(aValues)], varVariant);
      for I := Low(aValues) to High(aValues) do
        Result[i] := aValues[i];
    end;
```

After, I'm trying to pass this array (of type Variant) in the procedure, which is in my server module via client class TdmServerModuleClient, described above.
After, I'm going to convert the variant array into values of different types on the server side. But the TDBXCommand does not allow me to set the parameter value to be passed as Variant.

As for the phrase "you may just serialize those as text", could you explain (with code if possible) how I can deserialize such text in my server module?

Comment: Perhaps inspect the varType of your Variant and call appropriate Set* method.

Comment: What do you call a "variant array"? A SafeArray of variant values? If it is the case, you may just serialize those as text, not trying to pass the variants directly.

Comment: You have your code in front of you whereas readers do not.  So:  On what **exact** line do you get the error and what is the **exact** error message ("something like "SetVariant" is no use to readers).  Also, add the declaration of `FcallStoredProcedureCommand` to your q, please.

Comment: MartynA, Error message is "[dcc32 Error] uClientClasses.pas(80): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TObject' and 'Variant'". I have it on line "FcallStoredProcedureCommand.Parameters[1].Value.SetObjectValue(aParamValue‌​s);"